# ZF2: How to reset the ServiceManager during testing

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit, service-locator

My service manager is setup in my test bootstrap in what I suspect is a pretty standard manner, as follows:

```
    $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
    $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
    $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
    static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
```

In the base class of my unit tests I am accessing and configuring the service manager as follows:

```
    $this->sm = Test\Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
    $this->sm->setAllowOverride(true);
```

In my individual tests I am then overriding the services with mocks, using `$serviceManager->setService('MyService', $myMock)`.

This is fine except that I have to remember to unset each of the mocked services (which I am currently doing with `$serviceManager->setService('MyService', null)`, otherwise the tests intefere with each other.

Is there any easier way to reset the service manager to it's bootstrapped state after each test is run?  I can put a long list of services in the `setUp()` of the test base class and reset each there, but this could cause problems when a new service is added and the base class is not updated.  I thought about cloning the service manager before each test, but this could be problematic (due to shallow cloning).

I could, of course, bootstrap the service manager in the `setUp()` of the base test case, but this seems like a lot of processing overhead.

Any ideas?  Could peering be part of the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say using `setUp()` for setting up a new test with a new instance of `ServiceManager` and other fresh configurations is exactly how it is supposed to be done.